# how to export table in oracle 9i that excludes a column or two?

Tags: sql, oracle

is the text below works for the parameter file in exporting table in oracle  9i?

```
cat > test.par
GRANTS     = N
INDEXES    = N
ROWS       = Y
CONSISTENT = Y
TRIGGERS   = N
STATISTICS = NONE
TABLES     = table.table_name
QUERY = "where column_name not in ('col1','col2')
```

Comment: What's your thought about trying it first? Some, few, many of us doesn't have 9i to test, so you need to tell us the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` parameter can restrict the rows that are exported, not the columns.  If your goal is to export every row of data from the table but to avoid exporting the data from the columns `col1` and `col2`, I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: so what's your suggestion for this type of situation? yes, i dont want to export col1 and col2.

Comment: @NorieCrisSagun - As I said, I don't believe that is possible.  What is the business problem you're trying to solve?  Assuming that exporting is the only possible technical solution to that problem, you either need to export the entire table or you need to create a new table in the source database that has just the data you want to export and export that new table.

Comment: ah ok. so that's the most efficient way to do the export then. thanks. i thought there would be a way more direct to export the tables excluding one or two of its columns.